# Running script import from sub-directory

Tags: python, import

I have a folder structure like:

```
/app
    /folder
        file.py
    /folder2
        file2.py
```

I want to import a function from `file2` into `file1`.  How can I do this in Python 2?  It works in root to simply state:

```
from folder2.file2 import function
```

but when I use this statement in `file.py` it isn't able to find `file2`.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: I have init files in both folders, i just don't have one for the app